# Android - CardView give strange behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

here is my situation I have list view (RecyclerView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordiatelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/reload"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/questionlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/FloatingView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/questionlist"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_24dp"
         />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I maintain this recycle view with adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context _Context;

    private List<QuestionItem> Questions = new ArrayList<>();
    private API api;
    private int num;
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    public static final String BASE_POST_URl = "http://la3nyk.com/upload/";

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<QuestionItem> Questions) {
        this._Context = context;
        this.Questions = Questions;
        api = new API(context);
    }

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<QuestionItem> Questions,
            int num) {
        this._Context = context;
        this.Questions = Questions;
        this.num = num;
        api = new API(context);
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(_Context);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questions, null);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(_Context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/GE_SS_Two_Bold.otf");
        Typeface tfreg = Typeface.createFromAsset(_Context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/GE_SS_Two_Light.otf");

        ImageLoader _ImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(_Context).getmImageLoader();

        holder.imageView.setImageUrl( BASE_POST_URl + Questions.get(position).getQue_image_url(), _ImageLoader);
        holder.username.setTypeface(tf);
        holder.username.setText(Questions.get(position).user.username);
        holder.desc.setText(Questions.get(position).Que_Content);
        holder.desc.setTypeface(tfreg);
        holder.Date.setTypeface(tfreg);
        holder.Category.setText(Questions.get(position).category);
        holder.AnswersCount.setTypeface(tfreg);
        holder.Date.setText(Questions.get(position).Que_Date);
        holder.AnswersCount.setText(Questions.get(position).answers.size() + " " + _Context.getResources().getString(R.string.answers));
        holder.AnswersCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



//      if (num == 1)
//          Questions.get(pos).user.userimageURL = api
//                  .getSetting(AppConstants.TAG_user_photo);
//
//
//
//      if (Questions.get(pos).Que_image_url != null) {
//          if (!Questions.get(pos).Que_image_url.contentEquals("")) {
//              post_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//              //loader.DisplayImage(Questions.get(pos).Que_image_url, post_img,
//              //      post_img_pro, -1);
//          }
//      }
//
//

         //if (num == 1) {
         //arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.p_data_7);}
         //arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//      Animation animation = null;
//       animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(_Context,
//               R.anim.up_from_bottom);
//       animation.setDuration(500);
//          view.setAnimation(animation);
//            animation = null;
//
//      Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(_Context,
//              (pos > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
//                      : R.anim.down_from_top);
//      view.startAnimation(animation);
//      lastPosition = pos;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Questions.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected NetworkImageView imageView , post_img;
        protected TextView desc , Category ,username ,Date ,AnswersCount;
        protected ProgressBar userimageprog ,post_img_pro;
        protected ImageView arrow;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
             imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ques_user_img);
             desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ques_content);
             Category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
             post_img = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_img);
             userimageprog = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userimgae_prog);
             post_img_pro = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_img_pro);
             username = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_ques);
             Date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
             AnswersCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.answers_con);
            arrow = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        }
    }
}
```

CardView xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    cardview:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    cardview:cardElevation="2dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ques_user_img"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/userimgae_prog"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone" />


            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username_ques"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Asmaa Samir"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:text="2 days ago" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ques_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:text="ماهى اسباب ضعف الرؤيه أمام الحاسوب؟"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/qustion_8"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/answers_con"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="32 إجابه" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

here is my screenshot , 
**what is my question ?**

1- I got warp content cardview as appear in image.

2- my floating button appear down when view start load.

[image]

Comment: inflate with reference of parent, inflate(R.layout.questions, parent,false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the createViewHolder method of Adapter
change this

```
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questions, null);
```

to

```
  View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questions, parent,false);
```

We need to attach this card to the parent recyclerview to inherit its attribute